# Why does my component mount twice after fetching data from API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

TableHeader and TableBody component render twice after fetching data from API due to Table row are rendered twice and given duplicate key error in Reactjs.
Error : Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCJQa.png)

```js
         class Table extends React.Component {
          state = {
            headers: [],
            accesors: [],
            data: [],
            loading: true
          };

          componentDidMount() {
             instance.get('UserRole/GetDataList')
              .then(response => {
                var data = JSON.parse(response.data);

                this.setState({
                  headers: Object.keys(data[0]),
                  data: data,
                  loading: false
                }, () => this.setAccesors());


              }, error => {
                console.log(error);
              });
          }



          render() {
            const { headers, accesors, data } = this.state;
            if (this.state.loading ) {
              return "Loading...."
            }
            else {
              return (
                <table id="datatable-responsive" className="table table- 
                 striped table-bordered">
                  <TableHeader headers={headers} />
                  <TableBody  data={data} />
                </table>
              );
            }
            }
          }

          export default Table;
```

Comment: share code please

Comment: You can use conditional rendering and display Circular Loding component while data is being load and then render Table element after fetching all the data.

Comment: can you provide any stackblitz???

Comment: Please add TableBody and TableHeader code or create a codesanbox of your issue, that would help us debug. If you are seeing unique key error then you're either not setting a key or it's not unique for the jsx which is generated in a loop. Indexes are not recommended as keys, read more [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)